# How do I grab a NAPTR record from an IP address in Python?

Tags: python, dns

I'm looking to do something like this in python using dnspython:

```
 dig @XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA -p 99 +short '1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.e164.arpa' naptr
```

I thought dns.resolver.query would be the way to go, but it seems to choke on the IP address.

My code:

```
for rdata in dns.resolver.query('XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA', 'NAPTR') :
print rdata.target
```

Output from running the code:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\src\dnslookup.py", line 12, in <module>
    for rdata in dns.resolver.query('XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA', 'NAPTR') :
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 920, in query
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 856, in query
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: In what way does it choke on the IP?

Comment: Added code & error to question.

Comment: It looks to me like you're querying against your nameserver, not your target IP.

Answer (score 1):

As OXC pointed out, your code is querying for the NAPTR record for XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA which is not the equivalent to your dig command.

Here is code that more closely matches your dig command:

```
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = ['XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA']
resolver.port = 99

resolver.query('1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.e164.arpa', 'NAPTR')
# Need to confirm syntax for NAPTR query
```